# How do I call Watch extension functions from an iPhone and vice versa

Tags: ios, watchkit, healthkit

I have an iPhone app with a watch extension, the watch extension collects heartrate data and i want to display an average heartrate on the phone.

There is a button to start collecting heartrate data on the watch in an HKWorkoutSession and push it to HealthStore. I want this button to start a countdown timer on the iphone app and subsequently have the end of the timer cause the watch to stop collecting heartrate data.

My idea was to have the button that starts the workout session also call the function that starts the timer but i cant seem to do this since they are technically in 2 different apps. Is there any way to facilitate the sending of messages from one app to the other such that they could call functions or tell the other apps to call functions?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `WCSession`.

Check this.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession